# How can I display the first 25 prime numbers?

Tags: python

How can I display the first 25 integer prime numbers in the given interval? I can't find a way to limit it to 25 integer prime numbers.

```
minimum = 1000000000
maximum = 9999999999
print ("The first 25 10-digit prime numbers are:")
for num in range (minimum, maximum + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
    else:
        print(num)
```

Comment: Creating a counter variable would solve the problem. Just add the condition `if counter>=25: break` before the `print(num)`. And add `1` to it whenever the loop completes successfully.

Comment: Just create an iterator and stop after 25 numbers. Looking up the `yield` keyword would probably be enlightening.

Comment: Some performance hints: When testing for primality it is sufficient to 1) only test divisors up to `sqrt(num)` and 2) only test 2 and odd divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
from sympy import isprime
i=1
count = 0
while count < 25:
    if isprime(i):
        print(i)
        count += 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to use a counter to store how many prime numbers you've found.

```py
minimum = 1000000000
maximum = 9999999999
print ("The first 25 10-digit prime numbers are:")
counter = 0
for num in range (minimum, maximum + 1):
    if counter == 25: break
    if num > 3:
        for i in range (2, int(num/2)): # for optimization
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            counter += 1
            print(counter,num)
    else:
        counter += 1
        print(counter,num)
```

here is the more optimized code with the hints in the comments:

```py
import math
minimum = 1000000000
maximum = 9999999999
print ("The first 25 10-digit prime numbers are:")
counter = 0
for num in range (minimum, maximum + 1):
    if counter == 25: break
    if num > 3:
        if (num % 2) != 0:
            for i in range (3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(num)), 2):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                counter += 1
                print(counter,num)
    else:
        counter += 1
        print(counter,num)
```

Comment: for i in range (3, int(math.sqrt(num)), 2):    what is the number 2 for?

Comment: it's the step for the `range` variable. it iterates over only odd numbers from 3

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, you could use a variable to keep track of how many you've printed and `break` from the outer loop when that hits 25.

Here's an example, added to your code.

```py
minimum = 1000000000
maximum = 9999999999
printed = 0
print ("The first 25 10-digit prime numbers are:")
for num in range (minimum, maximum + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
    else:
        print(num)
        printed+= 1

    if printed >= 25:
        break
```

Comment: I'm a beginner, how can I do that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @A.Brusola I've updated my answer to demonstrate.